# sing Variable in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Using Variable in MySQL

I have tried many possibilities and consulted a number of sources but still not have been 
able to insert a string into a MySQL command in php.

Code below works well

```
 $SQL = 'INSERT INTO tb_addressbook (`ID`, `First_Name`, `Last_Name`, `Address`) VALUES (\'24\', \'JJ\', \'Gates\', \'Microsoft\');';
```

Code below does not work

```
 $SQL = 'INSERT INTO tb_addressbook (`ID`, `First_Name`, `Last_Name`, `Address`) VALUES (\'27\', \''.'"$first"'.'\''.', \'Gates\', \'Microsoft\');';
```

Can you help?

P.S. Is there a special way to insert a string for numbers?

Hugh
hugh@hahaggerty.com

Comment: Learn about prepared statements.

Comment: Your concatenation is off. See `'"$first"'` so `$first` won't be the variable and it will be inside single then double quotes. Try echoing the query in the future to debug. Also using prepared statements as noted above you wouldn't have to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO tb_addressbook (ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Address) VALUES ('27', '".$first."', 'Gates', 'Microsoft')";
```